# Django base.html

Tags: python

Подскажите как в Django admin передать переменную в шаблон base.html

В тулбаре хочу выводить информацию с базы данных, но не знаю как передать ее в base.html.

---

```
class ConferenceAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = Conference
    add_form = UserCreationForm
    form = UserChangeForm
    list_display = ('username','first_name', 'last_name', 'max_device', 'current_device','subordinate_max_device','subordinate_current_device', 'last_login', 'date_joined','is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active')
    list_display_links = ('username',)
    list_filter = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'max_device',)
    list_editable = ('max_device',)
    readonly_fields = ('date_joined', 'published', 'last_login', 'subordinate_max_device','subordinate_current_device')
    change_form_template = old_template
    add_form_template = old_template
    all_mac = Conference.objects.count()





    add_fieldsets = (
        (None,{
            'fields':( 'username','password1','password2','first_name','last_name','max_device')
        }),
    )


    def has_view_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            self.list_display_links = None
            self.list_display = ('username','first_name', 'last_name', 'max_device', 'current_device', 'last_login', 'date_joined' )
            self.fieldsets =          (
                (None,{
            'fields':('username','first_name', 'last_name', 'max_device', 'current_device', 'last_login', 'date_joined')
        }),

    )
            return super(ConferenceAdmin, self).has_view_permission(request, obj=None)
        return super(ConferenceAdmin, self).has_view_permission(request, obj=None)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):

        current_nondomain_mac = NonDomainUser.objects.filter(chief=obj.username)
        count_mac_chief = current_nondomain_mac.count()
        obj.subordinate_current_device = count_mac_chief
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Видите, все рендериться в другие в шаблоны. Если я отрендерю в base.html то я не смогу передать переменные в другие шаблоны

base.html

Comment: Точно так же, как выполняется передача любых переменных в любой шаблон

Comment: Не получается. В классе UserAdmin можно использовать только заранее известные функции которые в конце рендерят шаблон. Все эти функции связаны с изменением форм и так званый "екстра контент" ты передаешь в другой шаблон (к примеру change_form.html). А как передать именно в base.html непонятно. Сейчас в низу выложу примеры своих конфигов

Comment: Не надо выкладывать "внизу". Поле "ваш ответ" предназначено исключительно для публикации решений того, что приведено "в первом посте" (самом вопросе). Нажимайте "править" на вопросе и дополняйте. (Перенёс из ответа в вопрос, рассчитываю, что дальше сами)

Comment: Может для этого стоит переписать AdminSite ?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась расширением процессора контекста. Который позволил добавить переменную как дефолтную сразу во все шаблоны